# How to deduce template parameters based on return type?

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

I am attempting to create a simple `input()` function in C++ similarly to Python. I expected the code (below) to prompt the user for their age, then to print it into the console.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int age;
    age = input("How old are you? ");

    cout << "\nYou are " << age << endl;
}
```

I have written the following simple code to solve the problem

```
template <typename T>
T input(const string &prompt)
{
    T _input;
    cout << prompt;
    cin >> _input;

    return _input;
}
```

Instead it gives me the following error message:

```
In function 'int main()':
17:36: error: no matching function for call to 'input(const char [18])'
17:36: note: candidate is:
5:3: note: template<class T> T input(const string&)
5:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
17:36: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'
```

How do I make it so that `input()` automatically detects the fact that age is an int, and that I don't have to write `input<int>()`?

I don't need a function template necessarily, any solution will do that lets the code in `main` work as written.

Comment: That's not possible in C++. You can't deduce a template parameter based on the type of the variable you assign the result into. You either have to specify `int` as a template parameter, or pass `age` in as an argument.

Comment: @cigien isn't there another way to do it, be it by rewriting completely the function? Is there absolutely no way to edit get any type of input?

Comment: There are definitely ways to mimic the behavior you want. See the answer below for an approach using conversion operators. You'll need to create a class for it though, you can't do it with just a function template afaik.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conversion operators can mimic that.

```
struct input {
   const string &prompt;

   input(const string &prompt) : prompt(prompt) {}
   
   template <typename T>
   operator T() const {
       T _input;
       cout << prompt;
       cin >> _input;
       return _input;
   }
};
```

Mind however that this may not be applicable for *every* sort of operation. Plus, this is a fairly naive way of holding on the the `prompt`. You'd need to copy it proper if object lifetime issues become a concern.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't actually work with me. Interestingly, it ends up removing the first characters of the prompt if I input a number, and I have no idea why. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: @CloudWorm - It doesn't work for you because you very likely did something different. This class works [**as is** for your original example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qgBG04mfewWoQHBj).

Comment: It works for an int but not for std::string, unfortunately.

Comment: @CloudWorm - No solution would work for a class with overloaded assignment operators. Even a hypothetical function won't (assuming it was possible). You can either make it work by avoiding c-style anti-patterns (don't declare the variable at the top of the function and then assign, but rather declare and initialize it when you need) , or by using a function and specifying the template argument explicitly.